# Compute the dot product

Tags: vectors, inner-products

Let $\hat{u}$ and $\hat{v}$ be two unit vectors

Compute the dot product between $\hat{u}-4\hat{v}$ and $\hat{u}+4\hat{v}$

How do I go about solving this? This is the first time I've encountered a question like this and I'm really confused. I would appreciate it if anyone is willing to explain.

If $\hat{u}$ and $\hat{v}$ are unit vectors, do I just multiply everything by $1$? Also, does $\hat{u} = \hat{i}$ and $\hat{v} = \hat{j}$ or am I thinking about this the wrong way?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1):

Let $V$ be a vector space over the field $F$ with inner product $\langle \cdot \rangle$.

**Remark**

For $u\in V$ we define the norm of $u$ as  $\mid \mid u \mid \mid =\sqrt{\langle u,u \rangle}$.

For $u,v\in V$ we define their inner product as $\langle u,v\rangle\in F$ and we know that the inner product is a **bilinear form** (it means that is linear in each coordinate).Therefore if we remember that a inner product is symetric,we can easily calculate the required inner product(assuming that $F=\mathbb{R}$ otherwise we should use $\langle u,v \rangle=\overline{\langle v,u \rangle}$ where $\overline{\langle v,u\rangle}$ denotes the usual complex conjugate of a complex number).
$$\langle u-4v,u+4v \rangle=\langle u-4v,u \rangle+\langle u-4v,4v \rangle$$
$$=\langle u,u \rangle-4\langle v,u \rangle+4\langle u,v \rangle-16\langle v,v \rangle$$
$$=(\mid \mid u \mid \mid^2-4^2\mid \mid v\mid \mid^2)$$
Now if $u$ and $v$ are unitary vectors, what can you said about their norm?

Comment: You have assumed the two vectors are orthogonal? Did the problem state that? Also, you're using language that is far more advanced than the level of the OP, so be aware.

Comment: I do not assume that the vectors are orthogonal, since the argue works for arbitrary vectors $u,v$

Comment: Ah, I didn't pay enough attention. You're certainly using that $F=\Bbb R$ to get symmetry here. But, once again, your language is too advanced.

Comment: Yeah, I'm still lost looking at the answer. I'm taking Linear Algebra I at university, and I agree with @TedShifrin that the language is more advanced than I can handle for my level. I would appreciate it if you Brien Navarro or someone else can give a more simplified version of the answer.

Comment: @RomanArefov  Just ignore the words and use the properties you know of dot product. Use the distributive property and write out the four terms.

Comment: @TedShifrin, that's a lot more easy to understand. I will try that, thank you!

Comment: Yes I am agree with Ted Shifrin  in this problem the most important is know the properties of the inner product, in this case that in the field of real numbers we can ignore the complex conjugate, and the linearity of the inner product in each coordinate.